# Uploading files using Python requests module

Tags: python, python-requests

I need to load a file using a soap endpoint url...When I use the below code to load it the files are getting loaded but they are not in a readable format...When I load using SOAPUI tool it loads properly...

```
import requests

xml = '''<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                xmlns:v1="http://s.sa.com/services/Attachment/v1.0">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v1:attachment>
         <filename>FUZZY.csv</filename>
         <data>cid:138641430598</data>
      </v1:attachment>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>'''
target_url =  'https://s.sa.com:443/soatest/FileAttachmentService'
headers = {'Content-Type': 'text/xml','charset':'utf-8'}
r = requests.post(target_url,data=xml,headers=headers,auth=('3user1',''))
print 'r.text = ', r.text
print 'r.content = ', r.content
print 'r.status_code = ', r.status_code
```

New changes:-

```
files = {'file':open('./FUZZY.csv','rb')}
print files
r = requests.post(target_url,files=files,data=xml,headers=headers,auth=('p3user1',''))
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "soapcall_python.py", line 18, in <module>
    r = requests.post(target_url,files=files,data=xml,headers=headers,auth=('p3user1',''))
  File "/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-2.3.0-py2.7.egg/requests/api.py", line 88, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-2.3.0-py2.7.egg/requests/api.py", line 44, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-2.3.0-py2.7.egg/requests/sessions.py", line 418, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-2.3.0-py2.7.egg/requests/sessions.py", line 356, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
  File "/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-2.3.0-py2.7.egg/requests/models.py", line 297, in prepare
    self.prepare_body(data, files)
  File "/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-2.3.0-py2.7.egg/requests/models.py", line 432, in prepare_body
    (body, content_type) = self._encode_files(files, data)
  File "/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-2.3.0-py2.7.egg/requests/models.py", line 109, in _encode_files
    raise ValueError("Data must not be a string.")
ValueError: Data must not be a string.
```

Comment: When "they are not in a readable format", what _are_ they? What arrives on the other side, and what did you _want_ to arrive on the other side?

Comment: I see some non printable characters with only 1 line...The FUZZY.csv is a huge file with some valid data content...

Comment: Meanwhile, you don't seem to be sending the body of `FUZZY.csv` anywhere, just an attachment reference to something that doesn't actually exist. What you probably want to do here is [send a multipart encoded message](http://www.w3.org/TR/SOAP-attachments#SOAPReferenceToAttachements), which you can do [like this](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't sending the contents of the file anywhere. You're just sending a reference to a file that doesn't exist anywhere that the server can see.

As the docs for [SOAP references to attachments](http://www.w3.org/TR/SOAP-attachments#SOAPReferenceToAttachements) explains, the way you do this is to send a MIME-multipart message. If you're using the CID reference mechanism, that `cid` isn't some arbitrary string, it has to match the `Content-ID` header of a message in the MIME envelope.

The `requests` docs for [POST a Multipart-Encoded File](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) explain how to send the contents of a file as a message within a MIME request; briefly:

```
with open('FUZZY.csv', 'rb') as f:
    files = {'file': f}
    r = requests.post(target_url,
                      data=xml, headers=headers, auth=('3user1',''), 
                      files=files)
```

However, this simple method doesn't give you access to the Content-ID that will be generated under the covers for your message. So, if you want to use the CID reference mechanism, you will need to generate the MIME envelope manually (e.g., by using [`email.mail.MIMEMultipart`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/email.mime.html)) and sending the entire thing as a `data` string.

Comment: Thanks abarnett..I added your new changes but get an error "Data must be a string"...I have added the contents in the main message above...

Comment: @user1050619: Ah, I guess you can't send string `data` and `files` at the same time… But anyway, if you read my answer, it explains that this simple method will not work for you anyway, so why are you expecting it to work? You will need to either use a different reference mechanism, or generate the MIME envelope manually.